# Replace empty lists with tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Given a list of tuples, the following code removes the empty lists and prints out the remaining elements:

```
tuples=[[(16, 178)], [], [(46, 183)], [(15, 55)], [(42, 79)], [(54, 192)], [], [(2, 86)], []]

res = [ele for ele in tuples if ele != []]
print(res)
```

I now want to replace the empty lists with the tuple `[(0,0)]`. However, this line gives me an 'invalid syntax' error:

```
res = [ele=[(0,0)] for ele in tuples if ele != []]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a conditional expression in the comprehension:

```
res = [ele if ele else [(0,0)] for ele in tuples]
```

You could also just use `or`:

```
res = [ele or [(0,0)] for ele in tuples ]
```